# How to create my own name attribute in CakePHP Form?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3. I would like to generate my own style input tag. My code is:

```
     <?php
echo $this->Form->input(
                   'rpassword', array(
                   'class' => 'form-control placeholder-no-fix',
                   'type' => 'password',
                    'autocomplete' => 'off',
                    'placeholder' => 'Re-type Your New Password'
                   )
              );
        ?>
```

It generates HTML as follows:

```
 <input name="data[Reseller][rpassword]" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix " autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-type Your New Password" type="password" id="ResellerRpassword" >
```

But I want to set name attribute as 'rpassword'  only. My expected HTML is:

```
 <input name="rpassword" class="form-control placeholder-no-fix " autocomplete="off" placeholder="Re-type Your New Password" type="password" id="ResellerRpassword" >
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `name` attribute in the `input` parameters like `'name' => 'rpassword'`:-

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'rpassword', array(
        'class' => 'form-control placeholder-no-fix',
        'type' => 'password',
        'name' => 'rpassword',
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'placeholder' => 'Re-type Your New Password'
    )
);
```